# Calculate correlation between 4d numpy arrays in 4th dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 4d numpy arrays and some of the rows will be all zero:

```
a = np.random.rand(360).reshape(4, 5, 3, 6)
b = np.random.rand(360).reshape(4, 5, 3, 6)
a[0,1,0,:]=0
b[0,1,0,:]=0
```

I want to calculate the correlation between the two 4d numpy arrays in the forth dimension, so that I can get a 3D numpy array with dimension of (4, 5, 3). Each cell represent the correlation value in the new 3D numpy array.

For example the new 3D array [0, 0, 0] position is calculated from :
`np.corrcoef(a[0, 0, 0, :], b[0, 0, 0, :][1][0]`

Instead of loop through all the positions, is there a effecient way to do this?

Moreover, since some of my 4th dimension are all zero, the `np.corrcoef` produces nan,I also need to change those "nan" into 0.

Thanks in advance. Any insight is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replicate the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient):

```
corrs = (a*b).mean(axis=-1) - a.mean(axis=-1) * b.mean(axis=-1)
std_prod =  np.sqrt(np.var(a, axis=-1) * np.var(b, axis=-1))

out = corrs / std_prod

out = np.where(np.isnan(out), 0, out)
```